# How to write regular expression for this case?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regular expression in javascript to match the following valid scenarios. later on, If I have to extract using a group then I will be able to do so.

I have tried the below regex, but it not giving me the desired pattern.

```
/[0-9][+-[0-9]+]*/
```

Regex should be able to match the "Valid" scenarios.

```
// Valid
64344
   9434
  434-543 
434-543   
434  -   543
4435 - 343434
1-2,3,5,6 
1-2,3,5,6-6,45-4 
3,5,6, 8 -  9,24 
   1-2,3,5 ,6  
1-  2,3,  5,6-6,45-4



// Invalid
23 -
2343.3434
343.3434 - 13.466
23 ,
234,
,54
xyz   9
3,5,6,8-9,24,
,35,65,65
,35,65,65 -
,3  5,65,65,
3,5,6, 8-  9,24,
1-  2,3,  5,6-6,4 5-4
,  35,65,6 5
,35,  6  5,65,
```

Comment: Examples are helpful, but instead of *only* examples, you should also describe what the regex is supposed to match and what you were trying to accomplish with what you wrote.

Comment: I am not sure why people are downvoting this question. The provided regex covers almost all valid cases https://regexr.com/46l4l 
The user only needs a little more help, doesn't seem like he doesn't know that he is doing.

Comment: I agree with Ry-, it seems like these are just random examples.  I can't tell what it's actually supposed to do

Comment: I think the given samples are enough to conclude what he really wants although I agree it would have been helpful if he added some rationale behind it to make it more precise

Comment: this would be a great time to start learning how to write parsers :D

Comment: Please check [someone-answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your samples, I feel what you want is a comma separated numbers where some of which can be ranged like `1-2` and also having optional spaces between them and also at start or end of string. Here is a regex you can use,

```
^\s*\d+(?:\s*-\s*\d+\s*)?(?:\s*,\s*\d+(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?)*\s*$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `\s*` - optional space at start of input
- `\d+` - Matches one or more just number
- `(?:\s*-\s*\d+\s*)?` - This matches a ranged number like this `-2` which can have spaces within it and `?` at the end means ranged part is optional
- `(?:\s*,\s*\d+(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?)*` - This regex part ensures that the numbers can be comma separated and `\d+(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?` part in it enables numbers of `2-3` form where `?` in it indicates that it can be just pure number without having ranged part and `*` whole of this can be zero or more times
- `\s*` - optional space at the end of input
- `$` - end of input

**[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JKMVeU/1)**

Comment: Thank you so much for your replay. It is working fine.

Comment: Glad to know I was able to access your requirement and able to help you with a solution but like others also said, you should also give some reasoning behind the  post as it really helps others to help you. And I just looked at your positive samples only to create the regex and it automatically rejected your invalid samples and I was kind of sure this is indeed what you would have needed.